# Are These Two Instance of the Same Class? (ReactiveCocoa Documentation Examples)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, reactive-cocoa

I don't understand where the RACSignal object comes from in the following example in the ReactiveCocoa github documentation.

Under [Parallelizing independent work](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa#parallelizing-independent-work), it first shows the classic objective-c version:

```
__block NSArray *databaseObjects;
__block NSArray *fileContents;

NSOperationQueue *backgroundQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
NSBlockOperation *databaseOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    databaseObjects = [databaseClient fetchObjectsMatchingPredicate:predicate];
}];
```

Clearly, `[databaseClient fetchObjectsMatchingPredicate:predicate]` returns an array. But, in the reactive version:

```
RACSignal *databaseSignal = [[databaseClient
    fetchObjectsMatchingPredicate:predicate] // <== this should also be an array
    subscribeOn:[RACScheduler scheduler]]; // ,<== subscribeOn: is a RACSignal Method only
```

... it looks  like the same method is supposed to return not an array (which would have a rac_sequeance attribute) but a RACSignal.

In this example, is it meant to be read that `databaseClient' class in the RAC example is actually a subclass of RACSignal? Or, is a signal being created in some way not shown?

Currently running MacOS 10.9.3 with Reactive Cocoa 2.3. Documentation is from the ReactiveCocoa 3.0 branch.

Comment: Not sure if I agree with the title edit, it bigs the questions as to the answer.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question, then. Can you clarify the question and re-title it?

Comment: Why does `fetchObjectsMatchingPredicate` return an array in the top version but apparently a signal in the bottom? Is `database` presumed to be the same class in each example or two different classes, one written for operations and one written for RAC? The documentation says that RAC example is just "cleaned up and optimized" version of the non-RAC version, which implies to me that it's the same class and method in both versions. If so, I don't understand where the signal came from.

Comment: This type of paralyzation is what I really need from RAC so it is important I understand how to go about getting it.

Comment: I've updated my answer below to try to be a bit more helpful in answering your exact question. Think of the ReactiveCocoa version of the class as completely different from the non-ReactiveCocoa version. It might be helpful for you to study the OctoKit source code, which has a lot of methods like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly idiomatic in ReactiveCocoa code to name a method that returns a signal in a similar fashion to a method that would return the value directly. In other words, even though the method that returns the signal doesn't actually perform the action directly (when the method is executed), it's given a method name that suggests that it does.

For example, a method that queries a database and returns the result of that query directly might be named like this:

```
- (DBResult *)queryDatabase:(DBQuery *)query;
```

Whereas a RAC-ified version of this method would probably be named like this:

```
- (RACSignal *)queryDatabase:(DBQuery *)query;
```

It might seem a bit unintuitive at first, because technically that method *doesn't* query the database – instead, it returns a signal that results in an action to query the database *when the signal is subscribed to* – but that's the convention. You don't have to observe the convention in your own code, but a perusal of the [OctoKit](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.objc/blob/master/OctoKit/OCTClient%2BGit.h#L24) source code will show you that it's not uncommon.

> In this example, is it meant to be read that `databaseClient` class in the RAC example is actually a subclass of RACSignal? Or, is a signal being created in some way not shown?

In this example, `databaseClient` is not a subclass of RACSignal. It is just an object that responds to the `-fetchObjectsMatchingPredicate:` message, and returns a RACSignal from the corresponding method. Hypothetically, the object's class might look something like:

```
@interface MyDatabaseClient : NSObject

- (RACSignal *)fetchObjectsMatchingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate;

@end
```

Comment: So the class of the database client is not the same in each example or at least fetch... method sometimes returns an array and others a signal?

Comment: Correct. The class is not the same. The example elides the details, but is intended to demonstrate a completely different method (that happens to have a very similar name) if the code is changed to use ReactiveCocoa.

Comment: Okay, that's what I wanted to know. I might mosey over and suggest they make that explicit.